# How do I use the IEEE bibliography commands?

Tags: bibtex, cross-referencing, ieeetran, ieee-style

I'm trying to layout a short article using the [IEEE](http://www.ieee.org/publications_standards/publications/authors/authors_journals.html#sect2) latex style guide. I'm having difficulty with the final part of their bibliography instructions as I want to reference an external `.bib` file. I have the `IEEEtran.cls` file and `IEEEtran.bst` file in my local folder.

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
% argument is your BibTeX string definitions and bibliography database(s)
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,../bib/paper}
```

What are 'string definitions'? I presume the bibliography database is the specific file I want to reference, which in my case is `../../references`

Answer (score 4):

A string definition is an alias that shortens the work of bibtex-ing.

```
@STRING{HH = "Proc. IEEE Solid State Sensors Workshop"}
```

It goes, obviously, into your bibtex file, usually the very top.

And yes, the bibliography database is your references in the bibtex format. As things stand now, your document thinks that your bibliography database is "IEEEabrv,..,/bib/paper}

So you need to do:

```
\bibliography{../../references}
```

You can use multiple files also. My bibliography for my last paper was:

```
\bibliography {%
  bib/fbe2,%
  bib/books,%
  bib/mags,%
  bib/phd,%
  bib/roc,%
  bib/SA,%
  bib/prevWrk,%
  bib/mems}
```

BTW, all my bib files end in .bib (e.g. books.bib), and you don't include the suffix in your declaration.

Comment: One should probably leave IEEEabrv in the argument of the `\bibliography` command, since it is a file with the IEEE abbreviations. See http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bibtex/IEEEabrv.bib

Comment: It does work when I leave the IEEEabrv argument out (just using \bibliography{../../references} )

Comment: @domwass - yes, you're correct. Thanks for the correction. @celenius - so just move the IEEEabrv file the same dir as your references.bib - and sudo check my answer as correct.

Comment: The BTW saved me.